# Is It Possible to fetch Parent Name of Target Object on ProcessInstance Object?

Tags: apex, approval-process, processinstancenode

We have Custom Tab '**Approval Request**' in our lightning application.The Purpose of this Tab is to display list of all the Pending Approval Process of all the objects.

If I want to query on ProcessInstanceWorkitem then I can query like this:

```
SELECT Id,ProcessInstanceId, ProcessInstance.TargetObjectId, 
                                  ProcessInstance.TargetObject.Name,
                                  ProcessInstance.TargetObject.Type, 
                                  ProcessInstance.CreatedBy.Name,
                                  ProcessInstance.CreatedDate,
                                  from ProcessInstanceWorkitem
```

Similar Query we use it in our apex code.

I want to fetch the **Parent Name of the Target Object** so that whenever I Open the Approval Request then I can see the Parent Name of my Target Object Record.

e.g. I have a approval Request on Child object 'Potential Risk' of Parent Opportunity.So when I see the Potential Risk Record in Approval then i**t should display Parent Record Name which is Opportunity Name too**.

I want to know if it is possible or not.As per the below link I am not able to get Parent Name of my Target object.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_processinstanceworkitem.htm

Can someone please suggest?

Answer (score 2):

This requires two queries because `TargetObject` field is polymorphic on `ProcessInstance`.

SFDC provides OOTB support for the TargetObject.Name, TargetObject.Type (an SObjectType) and (I can't remember) - system audit fields.

You will need to do a separate query on `Potential_Risk__c` using `ProcessInstance.TargetObjectId` to fetch any fields on the parent object